# While loop only runs one time

Tags: python, while-loop

As the title says, my while loop will only run once. The first time I run the code, it asks the input and I can answer all the questions in the History and Geo categories. Then I enter exit and try to run the code again and it will keep asking me what topic I want. It still stops if I enter exit, but I can't make it run so I can answer my questions again.

```
while True:
        choose = input("What topic would you like?")
        if choose.lower() == "history":
            import History
            continue
        elif choose.lower() == "geo" or choose.lower() == "geography":
            import Geo
            continue
        elif choose.lower() == "i'm done" or choose.lower() == "exit":
            print("Thanks for playing!")
            break;
        else: 
            print("Sorry, please enter a valid topic")
            continue
```

Comment: what do you want with `import ...`?

Comment: @LeiYang The import History and import Geo import different .py files that ask questions, like "Who was the first president of the US?" or "What is the capital of Paris?"

Comment: Modules are only imported once. If `import history` does something on import, you won't see it after the first time because its not imported again.

Comment: @tdelaney How do I get it to import again? Is that even possible?

Comment: @JohnMiller I dont think its possible

Comment: @EzyGrip Dang. Thanks for the help.

Comment: You can do it through the import libraries (don't know the details off hand) but generally its better to import once. Move the code in history.py to a function and call it. `import history; history.do_all_the_things()`. That's the more common way to do it.

Comment: It sounds like your question title is incorrect. The loop is running multiple times. But there's code in the loop that you expect to be doing something that isn't doing that something, which is different from the *loop* not running. Being precise about what is happening is often a large chunk of figuring out how to fix it. And relying on an import statement to run additional code is poor practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @tdelaney suggested in comments, it is not possible to import a module again.
What you can do is write a function in `History` and `Geo` and call them when required.

Try this:

for `History.py`

```
def askQuestion():
    print('the Question')
```

Doing same in `Geo.py`

for `main.py`

```
import History
import Geo  
while True:
    choose = input("What topic would you like?")
    if choose.lower() == "history":
        History.askQuestion()
        continue
    elif choose.lower() == "geo" or choose.lower() == "geography":
        Geo.askQuestion()
        continue
    elif choose.lower() == "i'm done" or choose.lower() == "exit":
        print("Thanks for playing!")
        break;
    else: 
        print("Sorry, please enter a valid topic")
        continue
```

Answer (score 0):

its not possible to import the .py files again. instead call the functions of those .py files. for example. if history.py has a function called `def questions()`
and geo has a function with the same name, you would modify your code like this

```
import History
import Geo

while True:
        choose = input("What topic would you like?")
        if choose.lower() == "history":
            History.questions()
            continue
        elif choose.lower() == "geo" or choose.lower() == "geography":
            Geo.questions()
            continue
        elif choose.lower() == "i'm done" or choose.lower() == "exit":
            print("Thanks for playing!")
            break
        else:
            print("Sorry, please enter a valid topic")
            continue
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

There are no way to run this code again after input exit. because break keyword terminate the loop that defined under the exit.

But you can use some tricks to continue the exit code.

```py
    while True: 
     choose = input("What topic would you like?")
     if choose.lower() == "history":
        import History
        continue
     elif choose.lower() == "geo" or choose.lower() == "geography":
        import Geo
        continue
     elif choose.lower() == "i'm done" or choose.lower() == "exit":
        print("Thanks for playing!")
        play_again = input("Are want to play again(y/N)?")
        if play_again.lower()=='y':
            continue
        else:
            break
     else:
        print("Sorry, please enter a valid topic")
        continue
```